# Actionscript 3.0 - detecting multiple instances already placed on stage and adding them to an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Right now I'm trying to make a game with dozens of the same, identical block being on stage and when the player hits the block, it stops. Right now, I've figured out how, using arrays, I can create multiple versions of the block automatically in code and place them on the stage, but I was wondering if there's any way that Actionscript can detect multiple instances of the same object placed on the screen by dragging and dropping in Flash, and adding those all to an array?

For example, instead of having the code place the blocks at specific x and y coordinates, I want to place them in the stage myself in the Flash editor and then have them all be a part of the same array or class or something that allows the same hit testing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make those blocks instance of a custom class (export to as -> custom class). Run a loop on the display list and check if the objects are instances of that custom class, eg:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < this.numchildren; i++)
{
    if(this.getChildAt(i) is MyCustomClass)
    {
        myarray.push(this.getChildAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.numchildren` in a `for loop` is a very BAD coding practice. Use : `var lng:int = numChildren ; for (var i:int = 0 ; i < lng ; i++) {...}`

Comment: I agree storing in variable is better in theory but only when performance is critical, in most normal cases it won't even make a speed difference. It is not a bad practice in that regard, it's a bad practice when performance and code execution speed is mandatory.

Comment: Performance and AS3 coding standards are important in all the cases, and there isn't any reason to make a bad practice instead of a good practice.